# Facebook Android Sdk 3.0.2 Post to me/feed doesn't look right

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the new Facebook Sdk 3.0 for Android and I'm trying to make a post to the user wall using the new Request of the Graph Api. Now, I'm able to make the post, but on the Facebook page it shows as if I shared a link (and I don't want that). My final goal is to make a post that looks like that: 
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1ARTDj6qtSx4-qZQ0ZU1sZZppEMYMti8zwFLTZneSm2o/edit

and when you click it you go to the Facebook app.
My code of the request:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", title);
params.putString("caption", caption);
params.putString("description", description);
params.putString("picture", imageURL);
params.putString("link", FACEBOOK_APP_URL);

Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed",
    params, HttpMethod.POST, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

At this point the code above is posting the correct image and text, but on the click you are transferred to the image url and on the post itself the title is "Alexander shared a link" and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this very simple library: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing. Maybe you will have to adjust lightly to support facebook sdk 3. Instead, you can use previous sdk version of Facebook and you will get exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks, it really does what I meant. But in the end I decided its best to use Facebook Open Graph, because it really gives you a lot of control about how the post and user activity is displayed.

Comment: I used the same code and instead of the parameters i passed my facebook app page content got posted on wall.

Comment: Please try below code as i suggest you as a answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
Session s = Session.getActiveSession();

Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(s, "Testing App For genral purpose", new Request.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            if (response.getError() == null)
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Status updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

        }
    });
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: if still facing prob than follow following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17035220/1915697