# Facebook intergration with Libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, libgdx

I'm trying to connect my app to facebook by sharing highscores and google play link of my app.  but the tutorials that I got from the web are all outdated.  Does anybody tried this with new facebook sdk? or any link that can help me with this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should look over their official tutorials
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/

And to implement them you need to already know how to add android native elements into libgdx
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements

Comment: I'm just new in java so I'm having a hard time understanding this.  I just want to create a button inside the game that shares score to FB just like how google play leaderboard works.  Thanks!

Comment: Is not that easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005926/share-link-and-text-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0